# Minimum purchase in the checkout page by address ( City for example )

Tags: prestashop

Hello to all the community,
Thank you in advance to whoever will take the time to answer me !
In fact, I want to find a solution to make the minimum purchase on the checkout page ( not on the cart page ) and it depends on the address city.
I already did it in Prestashop 1.6 but now I use Prestashop 1.7.7.1 I am obliged to override the cart Presenter but I didn't rich a convenient solution.
Even I purchased a module of minimum purchase by country and modified it to be by the city but the module itself is not stable and it didn't work properly and the support of the module cannot find a solution because it requires an override of the core of Prestashop in the Symfony code and it will affect all the order tunnel which is typically impossible.
This topic will be a real challenge for developers that they don't know the impossible !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just hardcode it in your TPL files using smarty and add some check there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply dear.
Exactly, this is the best and the easiest solution with handling the shipping method template by displaying a minimum purchase message instead of displaying the existing carriers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating a module, in CartPresenter class you have hook `overrideMinimalPurchasePrice`. You can hook your module to this hook and modify the `$minimalPurchase` value in your module according to your logic.

You said that price depends on the address's city. Well, in your hook you can get the address, because in Prestashop front-office you always have access to cart and cart might have delivery address id:

```php
public function hookOverrideMinimalPurchasePrice($params)
{
    $cart = $this->context->cart;
    $id_address = $cart->id_address_delivery;

    // If customer did not enter the address yet, the address id is 0.
    if($id_address != 0)
    {
        $address = new Address($id_address);
        $city = $address->city;
        if($city == 'New York')
            $params['minimalPurchase'] = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

You do not have to return anything in the hook, because in CartPresenter.php the hook is called with parameter being passed by reference:

```php
 Hook::exec('overrideMinimalPurchasePrice', [
    'minimalPurchase' => &$minimalPurchase,
 ]);
```